# Is there a list of common module name acronyms?

Tags: python

Is there a list of widely agreed upon common module name acronyms like `np` for `numpy` and `pd` for `pandas`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53641032/are-there-standard-aliases-for-modules-in-python

Comment: s/acronym/abbreviation/ ?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an "official" list of such acronyms/abbreviations. However, I'd like to keep my modules as consistent with commons as possible. Can even a small list of the most often used modules be provided?