# Why use `from module import A as A` instead of just `from module import A`

Tags: python, mypy

When reading source code of fastapi, this line make me fuzzy:

```py
from starlette.testclient import TestClient as TestClient
```

Why not just: `from starlette.testclient import TestClient`?

Comment: I don't think there is a difference.

Comment: there is no meaningful difference ... other than in the option they chose they could swap out the import and still refer to it as TestClient

Comment: There is a difference for downstream consumers of the library that use a type checker. See, e.g. https://github.com/google/jax/pull/7606 for an explanation of why one might use the "from ... import X as X" pattern.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the point of view of executable code, there is absolutely no difference in terms of the Python bytecode being generated by the two different code examples (using Python 3.9):

```
>>> dis.dis('from starlette.testclient import TestClient as TestClient')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (('TestClient',))
              4 IMPORT_NAME              0 (starlette.testclient)
              6 IMPORT_FROM              1 (TestClient)
              8 STORE_NAME               1 (TestClient)
             10 POP_TOP
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis('from starlette.testclient import TestClient')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (('TestClient',))
              4 IMPORT_NAME              0 (starlette.testclient)
              6 IMPORT_FROM              1 (TestClient)
              8 STORE_NAME               1 (TestClient)
             10 POP_TOP
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
```

As shown, they are exactly identical. (Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22245711/from-import-or-import-as-for-modules) asked before existence of [PEP-0484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/)).

However, [the comment by Graham501617](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72504576/why-use-from-module-import-a-as-a-instead-of-just-from-module-import-a#comment128825307_72504576) noted how modern type hinting validators (such as `mypy`) accept this particular syntax to denote the re-export of that imported name (the other being the [`__all__`](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/7042), which thankfully they did end up correctly supporting as that has been a [standard syntax to denote symbols to (re-)export since Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/what-does-all-mean-in-python)).  Specifically, as per the description of [Stub Files](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#stub-files) in the referenced PEP 0484, quote:

> - Modules and variables imported into the stub are not considered exported from the stub unless the import uses the `import ... as ...` form or the equivalent `from ... import ... as ...` form. (UPDATE: To clarify, the intention here is that only names imported using the form `X as X` will be exported, i.e. the name before and after `as` must be the same.)

Looking at [`git blame`](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blame/22528373bba6a654323de416ad5c867cbadb81bb/fastapi/testclient.py) for the relevant file in the packages pointed to [this commit](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/commit/fdb6c9ccc504f90afd0fbcec53f3ea0bfebc261a) ([direct link to relevant diff for the file](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/commit/fdb6c9ccc504f90afd0fbcec53f3ea0bfebc261a#diff-d8022eeae6cbeb462b6b560dd094399052441734772d7fc7fee1d0058c5e20a4)) indicated that this particular type hinting issue was being addressed (as part of [this issue](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/pull/2547)) to ensure mypy will treat those imported names as re-export, thus allowing the usage of the [`--no-implicit-reexport`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-no-implicit-reexport) flag (which [`--strict`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-strict) has likely implicitly enabled).

This particular re-export syntax however is very much strict about the "name before and after `as` must be the same", the syntax referred in the related question (i.e. `import foo.bar as bar`) can be found in recommendation by certain modern packages (e.g. PyTorch recommends the use of `import torch.nn as nn`, as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61471924/in-python-what-is-the-difference-between-import-foo-bar-as-bar-and-from-foo)), does not in fact allow the `bar` (or `nn`) symbol be re-exported from the current module as `foo.bar` is not the same as `bar` (likewise `torch.nn` is not the same as `nn`, as the whole set of tokens `torch.nn` is evaluated instead of the just the final identifier after the final `.`).